# How to disable GitHubSourceAction from triggering pipeline on push?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I have the following first stage in a pipeline that builds my app and deploys it to an S3 bucket behind a CloudFront distrubution:

```js
    pipeline.addStage({
      stageName: 'Source',
      actions: [
        new GitHubSourceAction({
          actionName: 'Checkout',
          owner: "au-research", 
          repo: "raido-v2",
          branch: "main",
          oauthToken: SecretValue.secretsManager(
            'ardc-shorn-github-personal-token' ),
          output: outputSources,
          trigger: GitHubTrigger.NONE,
        }),
      ],
    })
```

My understanding was that setting the `trigger` to `None` meant that the pipeline would only run if I trigger it manually.  But it seems to trigger whenever I push to Github.

When I edit the stage action manually, I only see the options for github or CodePipeline:
[image]

What CDK config can I use to make the pipeline only run when I do a manual "release change" action (via console or command line)?

Comment: You have an existing webhook in GitHub. You need to remove it manually on the github side.

Comment: @gshpychka - Ohhhh, right.  I have been fiddling with it a bit, there was probably one where I didn't have the trigger set to none.  And I did destroy and re-create it at least once.  If you want to add this as an answer I will mark it answered after I give it a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this happen due to leftover GitHub webhooks - even though the trigger is set to `NONE`, there may still be a webhook on the github side that is still triggering the build.

Go to `https://github.com/your-github-ord/your-github-repo/settings/hooks` and delete any webhooks you might have there.